# Goutte to get script element by type

Tags: php, dom, screen-scraping, goutte

I am trying to use Goutte to get the contents of a page, when veiwing the source there is a script that I want to get the contents of all the code in  ...

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "LocalBusiness",
"name" : "Example",
</script>
```

I am using something like this, which works for html elements but not the script element.

```
        $crawler->filter('.main_content')->each(function ($node) {
```

Once I have got the contents, I want to explode it by each element.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me:

$crawler->filterXpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]');

docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html